# php date misinterpretation

Tags: php, date

I run this:

```
echo date('l, F jS Y','2011-02-12 14:44:00');
```

I get this:

> Wednesday, December 31st 1969

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument for `date` needs to be a UNIX timestamp, not a date string. Use:

```
echo date('l, F jS Y', strtotime('2011-02-12 14:44:00'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php